# Connecting arduino due with android through USB cable

Tags: android, arduino

I just wanted to ask that can I connect android phones with the new arduino due board using USB cable just as we did  with the arduino mega adk board?

Comment: Might be a good question for electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have finally got my answer. Follow this link: [link](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=139279.15)